# How to replace string group with a string in eclipse

Tags: java, regex

I have a set of constant like this:

```
private static final transient String NOME_FILE_RC = "blabla1.xml";
private static final transient String NOME_FILE_NS = "blabla2.xml";
private static final transient String NOME_FILE_NE = "blabla3.xml";
private static final transient String NOME_FILE_DT = "blabla4.xml";
private static final transient String NOME_FILE_MC = "blabla5.xml";
private static final transient String NOME_FILE_NR = "blabla6.xml";
```

I want to replace `FILE` with `DOCUMENT` in eclipse

I set find with `\w{4}_(FILE)_\w{2}`
I know that `$1` catches `FILE` string but I don't know how to replace it with `DOCUMENT`.

Comment: I would do something like: Search: `(\w{4}_)FILE(_\w{2})` Replace with: `$1DOCUMENT$2`

Comment: AKA Perl style regular expression. Maybe even `\1DOCUMENT\2`

Comment: what would happen if you just find `FILE` and replace with `DOCUMENT`? I guess it would work for the example you pasted. or `_FILE_` ->`_DOCUMENT_` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `(\w{4}_)FILE(_\w{2})` instead and replace with `$1DOCUMENT$2`.

Comment: Best answer: clean, no comment, resolve problem and elegant, thanks

Answer (score 0):

capture the rest of the string

```
(.*?)FILE(.*)
```

and replace with

```
$1DOCUMENT$2
```